# upload images to java spring

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, backend

I am trying to upload an image from postman to a java spring controller

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadfile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void handleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    if (!file.isEmpty()) {
        try .....
```

Postman :

[image]
[image]

But i am getting this error message in java :

```
2019-11-24 18:46:48.861  WARN 4844 --- [nio-8088-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Integer'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "uploadFile"]
```

Anyone an idea what I am doing wrong??
I m just starting out so please don t cut my head off for asking!!

Comment: Add  `consumes = "multipart/form-data"` in `@RequestMapping`.

Comment: I did but nothing changed

Comment: Try this :`@PostMapping("/uploadfile")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public void handleFileUpload( @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){}`

Comment: still don t work...i really don t know what i m doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You have a method with the mapping `/uploadfile`, but call the different path 
 - `/uploadFile`.